# Dec Ada & exception

Tags: exception, ada

I have this code in one modules:

```
PROCEDURE Get (File: IN Ada.Text_IO.File_Type; Item : OUT Rational) IS

N: Integer;
D: Integer;
Dummy: Character;  

BEGIN -- Get
LOOP
BEGIN
  Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(File => File, Item => N);
  Ada.Text_IO.Get  (File => File, Item => Dummy);
  Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(File => File, Item => D);
  Item := N/D;
  if Dummy /= '/' then
   ........;
  end if;

EXIT;

EXCEPTION
     when other =>
          Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(" here is exception ");
END;
END LOOP;
END Get;
```

What is differences with this second code.

The main of my question is if I don't put **raise** in body of statement of exception what is happen?

```
PROCEDURE Get (File: IN Ada.Text_IO.File_Type; Item : OUT Rational) IS

N: Integer;
D: Integer;
Dummy: Character;  

BEGIN -- Get
LOOP
BEGIN
  Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(File => File, Item => N);
  Ada.Text_IO.Get  (File => File, Item => Dummy);
  Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Get(File => File, Item => D);
  Item := N/D;
  if Dummy /= '/' then
    ........;
  end if;

EXIT;

EXCEPTION
     when other =>
          Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(" here is exception ");
    **raise;**
END;
END LOOP;
END Get;
```

The main of my question is if I don't put **raise** in body of statement of exception what is happen???

Thank you very much.

Comment: This should be answerable by reading the chapter on exceptions in any book on Ada - or by experiment.

Comment: thank your very much of your response. but,  just wanted to know a generic answer. I want In a function, suppose which calls a number of functions in between, is it a good idea to keep the exception handler in the main function only or in all intermediate called functions where respective exceptions can be raised? . thank your

Comment: If your book on Ada is any good, it will explain approaches to exception handling. Where, when, and to what extent, what kind of exceptions, and so forth. One guideline question is this: does the outer subprogram "know" how to handle exceptions raised in inner subprograms?

Comment: @ B98 : the outer subprogram not "know" how to handle exceptions raised in inner subprograms.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between both code modules is that the exception (if any is raised during execution of Get) is reraised, i.e. the exception is propagated to the caller of Get.

Whether this is the desired behaviour depends on your needs, i.e. does the caller of Get need to know that an exception occurred?

In your example several kinds of exceptions may occur, e.g.

- not reading the correct/expected input  (the file to read from does not start with a number)
- trying to read from a file that has not been opened
- reading D as 0 (thus resulting in a division by 0)

All of these are handled in the same manner by printing "here is exception". The first implementation of Get then silently returns control to the caller (who will not know that anything strange happened). The second implementation, however, will inform the caller by reraising the exception.

For more information see the Ada LRM §11.3 (Raise Statements).